# Documents directory in Universal apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, synchronization, universal-binary

If an user has an iPad and iPhone, and synchronizes an Universal app which has stored files in the Documents directory in one of these devices (say iPhone), do these files become available to the other device (say iPad) after synchronizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't. Contents of the Documents and Library directory are not part of the sync process (iTunes backups them, though).